# Loop in directory using awk script that can be running using cmd line

Tags: batch-file, awk, cmd, gawk

I want to do some loop on files inside subfolders using awk script that I'm running it from cmd line script.
I'm using this code inside my cmd:

```
for /r %%I in (*.txt) do awk -f D:\Main\command.awk %%~fI 
pause
```

But I have these error rise:

> 'awk' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

But when I write it down manually on cmd line, it works just fine.
Does anyone know what is wrong with this?
Thank you.

Regards,
Bams

Comment: Your command will definitely *not* run on `cmd` if entered manually - you will see this error: `%%I was unexpected at this time.`. The `%%` notation is used in batch scripts only.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late update.
Here's the code that I made in `cmd` script.

```
@echo off

pushd "%~dp0"
for /r %%I in (*.txt) do C:\Progra~2\GnuWin32\bin\awk -f command.awk %%~fI >> result.csv

pause
```

and it works, so basically I notice the error was about working directory.